# Linear regression - Bayesian Predictive distribution

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, prior

I am trying to answer a question about linear regression but i am stuck:
$y=w \cdot x + \epsilon, \epsilon \sim N(0,\alpha)$

i am also given a prior:

$w\sim N(0,\beta)$

from which i was able to work out that:

$p(w|S)=const * exp(-\frac{1}{2\alpha} \sum (y^{i} - w \cdot x^{i})^{2}-\frac{1}{2\beta}w^{2})))$

Where $S$ is the sample training data

Now i want to work out $p_{y}(\bar{y}|S,\bar{x})$

where $\bar{y}$ is output when $\bar{x}$ is novel input data

I have been told to use marginal and conditional guassian linear models.

I am just confused on what to do now...